# Dynamic/responsive solution for overlapping div's

Tags: html, css

I'm developing more and more sites where the design includes overlapping elements, for example a text-box with an image on top of it.

This is an expamle of what I try to accomplish:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XSON.jpg

I try to find a good solution for it where it can be easily made responsive and not be broken if the content manager decides to make the text longer for example. And preferably also can easily be animated or made parralax.

At the moment I use a negative margin on my second element:

```
<div class="back"></div>
<div class="front" style="margin-top:-200px;"></div>
```

But thats probably not a good solution.

I apologize in advance if this question is asked here often.

Comment: `margin-top` is compatible with responsive design and dynamic content. If you want to achieve a **nice** design according to the content, I think the standard way is CSS media queries and different template for different resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution of using `margin-top` on the right `div` works.

One other solution to this would be to use `absolute` positioning on the two `div`s.

With `position: absolute`, you can give the `div`s each a `z-index`. Then give `.front` a higher `z-index` than `.back`, positioning `.front` "above" `.back`.

Assuming you want the two `div`s to be centered as a group in the page, but always maintaining the same positioning and distance to each other:

```
/* All px amounts are a wild guess. You can adjust to achieve the desired affect. */

.front {
    position: absolute; 
    top: calc(50% - 250px);
    left: calc(50% - 275px);
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(50% - 250px);
    right: calc(50% - 275px);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Assuming you want the two `div`s anchored to their respectives sides, only overlapping if the screen is small enough:

```
/* all top, left, bottom, and right values are approximations. */

.front {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```